# 'selected effect' on jquery tab (or other stuffs)

Tags: jquery, html, css

The 'selector effect' which is an orange border (can be seen here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) is annoying.. where does that come from? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're speaking about the outline a browser will add on anchor elements. Blue orange or whatever, depending on the browser.

This is a CSS fix.

```
.class-name {
outline: 0;
}
```

Please note: Removing outlines in this manner can prevent visually impaired users, or users without a mouse from accessing your content.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the CSS

```
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

if it doesn't work you may have to declare

```
:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```